# How to build a vector consisting arrays of different sizes in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, vector

I was solving a hackerrank problem named 'Variable Sized Arrays' where the problem statement is:

---

**Consider an n-element array,a, where each index i in the array contains a reference Kito an array of integers (where the value of Ki varies from array to array). See the Explanation section below for a diagram.**

**Given a, you must answer q queries. Each query is in the format i j, where i denotes an index in array and j denotes an index in the array located at a[i] . For each query, find and print the value of element j in the array at location on a[i]a new line.**

Input Format

The first line contains two space-separated integers denoting the respective values of n (the number of variable-length arrays) and q (the number of queries). Each line of the subsequent lines contains a space-separated sequence in the format k a[i]0 a[i]1 … a[i]k-1 describing the k-element array located at a[i]. Each of the q subsequent lines contains two space-separated integers describing the respective values of i (an index in array a) and j (an index in the array referenced by a[i]) for a query.

**Sample Input

2 2

3 1 5 4

5 1 2 8 9 3

0 1

1 3**

**Sample Output

5

9**

---

I am a beginner in c++, I did the code below:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    vector<int*> vec;
    int n,q;
    cin>>n>>q;
    ////Adding n arrays to the vector////
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {   
        int a;
        cin>>a;      ///// a is the length of the particular array
        int arr[a];
        for(int j=0;j<a;j++) {
            cin>>arr[j];
        }
        vec.push_back(arr);    ////// push the array in the vector
    }
    ////// Answering to queries /////
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++) {
        int y,z;            ///  z^th element in y^th array in the vector
        cin>>y>>z;
        int* arr;
        arr = vec[y];
        cout<<*(arr+z)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**This code only works for 1st array in the vector. For later arrays, it gives a random value.**
i.e. input:
2 4
3 1 5 8
5 1 2 8 9 3
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 2

Output:
5
8
7208632
4199698

Comment: `int arr[a];` -- This is not valid C++.  Why are you using this syntax when you are already using `std::vector`?  This should be `std::vector<int> arr(a);`  Then `std::vector<int*>` is just `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.  Then don't be surprised if your program magically works.

Answer (score 2):

You are not considering the **lifetimes** of the objects you are creating.

In this code the array `arr` exists only inside the for loop.

```
vector<int*> vec;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {   
    int a;
    cin>>a;
    int arr[a];                 // arr created here
    for(int j=0;j<a;j++) {
        cin>>arr[j];
    }
    vec.push_back(arr);
}                               // arr destroyed here
```

But you have a vector of pointers and you are storing a pointer to `arr` inside the vector. So your vector has pointers to objects which have already been destroyed. This leads to undefined behaviour.

C++ does not keep an object alive just because you are storing a pointer to it. So when you use pointers you must always consider how long the object you are pointing to is going to live.

The simple way to solve this is to use a vector of vectors.

```
vector<vector<int>> vec;      // change here
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {   
    int a;
    cin>>a;
    vector<int> arr(a);       // change here
    for(int j=0;j<a;j++) {
        cin>>arr[j];
    }
    vec.push_back(arr);
}
```

Now because you are not using pointers the `arr` is **copied** into the vector `vec`, so it doesn't matter that the original `arr` has been destroyed.

Try to avoid using pointers. There's very little need for them in C++.

Also the notation `int arr[a];` is a variable length array (VLA) because `a` is a variable not a constant. VLAs are not legal C++ and some compilers would not even compile your code.

Comment: The good thing is that it all boils down to one line, and changing that one line trickles up (or down) to the actual fixes to make.  That line being `std::vector<int> arr(a);`